# Represent a List of strings in GWT as widget in an editor

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-widgets

I'm building a GWT app.

I want to associate a list of items (List < String >) to an editor.

Is there any built in widgets that support editing list of items?

Something that will show comma separated values and will know how to render them back to the proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `CellList` widget to display a list of items. If you want to present them horizontal add `float:left` as style to the individual items in the Celllist style items: `cellListEvenItem` and `cellListOddItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, take a look at [CellTable](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your custom class for CellList and/or CellTable adapting for your needs. All components from gwt extends Widget, and can be extended too.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up with this Facebook auto complete style
http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/creating_a_facebook_style_autocomplete

And demo http://demo.raibledesigns.com/gwt-autocomplete/